# Android seekbar progress not update

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-seekbar

I am using seekBar for soundpool volume control on my app, I use PopupWindow for seekbar and everything works fine except, whenever I change or pause my activity, and I open seekbar popupwindow again, the seekbar is no longer the value I last had saved. But it always returns to its default value 100%, even I use SharedPreferences what works well, but only if I do not leave current activity.

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnMenuItemClickListener {

SoundManager snd;
OnSeekBarChangeListener barChange1;

private int soundID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
      }

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();



    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
         View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
         final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 


                     barChange1 = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
                     {


                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefsFilename1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        prefs.edit().putInt("seekBarValue", seekBar.getProgress()).commit();            

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                                 snd.setVolume((float)progress/100.0f);

                            }
                        };

                    SeekBar volbar1 = (SeekBar)popupView.findViewById(R.id.VolBar1);                
                    volbar1.setMax(100);                    
                    int value = 0;
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefsFilename1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    value = prefs.getInt("seekBarValue", 100);
                    volbar1.setProgress(value);
                    volbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(barChange1);


                    Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             popupWindow.dismiss();


                     }});

                             popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 60, 20);

                   }});
                        {
                }



      this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

      snd = new SoundManager(getApplicationContext());

      soundID = snd.load(R.raw.sound_1);



 ImageView img01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
 img01.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     }

                snd.play(soundID);
                return false;
        }           
    });
}



        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            snd.unloadAll();



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this onResume()

```
     int value = 0;
     SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefsFilename1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     value = prefs.getInt("seekBarValue", 100)
     volbar1.setProgress(value);
```

Comment: Hi, i try it but it makes my app crash.. must test more, maybe i do something wrong..

Comment: volbar1 is probably not initialized do this  volbar1 = (SeekBar)popupView.findViewById(R.id.VolB)

Comment: This is strange, in fact, seekbar works as it should but the volume from the device returns always to default 100%, if i pause or change activity..

Comment: I still have a problem, how to get both, "Soundpool volume" and "seekbar value" to updated onResume. The seekbar value update fine now, and it show my last position onResume, but soundpool Volume itself returns to its default value 100%, every time onResume. Pls help me!

Comment: Please post your entire code. Complete fragment code

Comment: Hi, i edited my code and now you can see complete code!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing. Its working for me. Here is my code. It does not have all the Sound stuff.

```
    package com.titlesource.testproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener barChange1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_main);
    }

    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                barChange1 = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
                {


                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefsFilename1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        prefs.edit().putInt("seekBarValue", seekBar.getProgress()).commit();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    }
                };

                SeekBar volbar1 = (SeekBar)popupView.findViewById(R.id.VolBar1);
                volbar1.setMax(100);
                int value = 0;
                SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefsFilename1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                value = prefs.getInt("seekBarValue", 100);
                volbar1.setProgress(value);
                volbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(barChange1);


                Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        popupWindow.dismiss();


                    }});

                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 60, 20);

            }});
        {
        }
    }
}
```